# What is the meaning of "/usr/bin/ip route add 180.151.157.4/32 via 0.0.0.0"

Tags: openvpn, iproute2, static-routes

In the process of setting up a VPN client side, openvpn tries to add a route but it fails:

```
/usr/bin/ip route add 180.151.157.4/32 via 0.0.0.0
RTNETLINK answers: No such device
```

The reason why we add a static route for ip 180.151.157.4 to 0.0.0.0 must be a trick because I can't give it any sense... I has something to do with replacing the default route for what I know but I'm not sure. Someone can explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that is a misconfiguration, though I'm not sure which.

Routes meant to be pushed to the client to go over the tunnel should be specified with a gateway of "gateway".  Also, in iproute2, locally attached subnets aren't specified with a gateway at all, just a device.

Routes via 0.0.0.0 are null routes, meaning that the traffic should be discarded.  This is normally valid.  However, in the context of iproute2, I think it's preferable (maybe required?) to specify a blackhole route, i.e.

```
ip route add blackhole 192.0.2.1/32
```

Comment: Indeed, this route is added because server pushed `--redirect-gateway def1`. I changed my network settings from PPPoE to "classic" router config and the route pushed is now : `/usr/bin/ip route add 180.151.157.4/32 via 192.168.1.1`.

Comment: That option only pushes routes for 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1...

Comment: My server push the following :  
  
    PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4,route 10.10.0.1,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 60,ifconfig 10.10.4.114 10.10.4.113'  
  
So I replaced the `pull` in my client with those commands. I tried whith `redirect-gateway` and without. The difference I noticed is in those 3 routes :  
  
    /usr/bin/ip route add 119.9.85.24/32 via 192.168.1.1  
    /usr/bin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.10.4.113  
    /usr/bin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.10.4.113